# E Commerce and cross domain tracking on universal analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, e-commerce

I am running into an issue where my client's website (can refer to domain.com) uses a third party checkout site called rezovation that we can refer to checkout.rezovation.com: I went through this doc here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain and the google setup e-commerce doc (for universal analytics) and I still find it confusing so here are my questions:

1) According to my understanding I need a customized GATC to link both domains checkout.rezovation.com and domain.com?

2) If yes(above), do we setup one customized GATC for cross domain tracking on all pages from checkout.rezovation.com and domain.com? if it is the case can someone provide detail steps on how to set it up (I am not a coder so the easier the guideline, the better)

3) Once cross domain tracking is set up, e commerce tracking code should be only on thank you page should be looking like the image below?

[image]

4) Should I add manually all the extra code for the e-commerce tracking code or I can get it done via a third party website?

Comment: Hi everyone

I guess it is a tough question. Please let me know if you need more information.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The question really is:  Will they (Rezovation) allow a customized version of the GATC?  From what I've seen from them, the answer to that is no.   Again, from what I've seen, which is only a a screenshot of the interface where you enter your GAUA number.   Ultimately you get in-actionable data that doesn't even pass room nights booked and cannot be attributed to the proper source.

Perhaps they offer another plan that allows true cross domain tracking.  It's a shame they don't have it built in because with Universal Analytics it's an extremely easy and consistent customization that would only require one additional input from their clients.

-Theo